# Maven won't compile Java annotations?

Tags: java, maven, compilation, annotations

I'm having trouble getting maven to compile a project that uses Java annotations.  I get the following error message:

```
annotations are not supported in -source 1.3 (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
@PostConstruct
```

In my POM I have the following compiler plugin so for a start where is it getting -source 1.3 from?

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I suspect I am probably missing something very simple to get this working but googling the error doesn't bring up anything helpful

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: is that pom snippet in build->plugins?

Comment: That's the correct XML for that plugin to provide 1.6. The problem lies elsewhere in a section you're not showing us, or that entry is in the wrong place.

Comment: You should copy your full pom, there's probably a configuration problem somewhere else. I suggest trying to start with a minimal pom with nothing but one class using an annotation, see if that's working. If it is, then slowly add the other components, one by one, until it stops working. You get your culprit.

Comment: Yes it is in the build/plugins section, I can't show the whole POM for confidentiality reasons.  Strangely upgrading to Maven 3x versus Maven 2x fixes this problem so maybe a Maven rather than a POM issue?

Comment: @RobV, no, it's not a Maven issue. It works just fine for millions of other developers. If you can't post a POM, there's really no way anyone here can help you find what you're doing wrong. If upgrading to 3.x is fixing the problem, there was something in the maven2 config that was overriding your POM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your `<plugin>` element is inside `<build>` section and not only in `<pluginManagement>` or `<reporting>` sections.